# Removing file, which was temporarily created for gm stream

Tags: javascript, meteor, graphicsmagick, collectionfs

I'm using collectionFS and gm for some image mainpulation in my meteor app. I'm creating a temporary file:

```
    var fs = Npm.require('fs');
    var filename = '/tmp/gm_' + Date.now();
    var read = file.createReadStream('source'),
    var temp = fs.createWriteStream(filename);

    gm(read)
    .crop(100, 100, 10, 10)
    .stream().pipe(temp);

    // Do some more things

    // remove temp-file
```

At the end I want to delete this temporary file. How do I do that? I'm not very familiar with streams... 
I think of something like `fs.remove(filename)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for this guy: `fs.unlinkSync(filename);`